# How to use tls certificate instead of ssl

Tags: ssl

My question is How to use tls instead of ssl.I have gone through ssl provider websites,there I got ssl/tls certificate.Is tls come by default with ssl certificate.Can we buy tls separately.Whether I have to force certificate....

Answer (score 1):

The certificate that one gets from the `CA (Certificate Authority)` can be utilized for both `SSL` And `TLS`. I do not believe or have seen a CA can isolate a certificate to be only used for TLS (or if it is even possible in terms of the X509 specification to isolate that a certificate can be used only for TLS).

However, with the recent attacks in the picture that cannot be prevented by the `SSL` protocol such as `Poodle` being just one (for `SSL` and `CBC` ciphers), `SSL` v3 (which is the last `SSL` version in use) is being unsupported as I write this or has already been - both by browsers and web servers.

If you do not desire to use `SSL` and use `TLS` exclusively (which is the right thing to do in order to be as secure as one can be), you would need to configure that in the web server (assuming you are using HTTPS). Each web server has a way to specify the

1. SSL / TLS versions to support (you would simply disable SSL and enable TLS versions exclusively)
2. Secure cipher suites
   and so on.

A simple google can get you all the information on Apache, Nginx or whatever web server you use or for that matter a TLS client such as a browser, JSSE based etc.

Answer (score 0):

TLS and SSLv3 do not depend on your certificate. The procedure to import the cert will remain the same regardless. What you need to do is disable SSL v3 using your web server (be it Apache or Netscape etc).